# Using Stoke's theorem evaluate the line integral $\int_L (y i + zj + xk) \cdot dr$ where $L$ is the intersection of the unit sphere and x+y = 0

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_L (y i + zj + xk) \cdot dr$$ where $L$ is the intersection of the unit sphere and $x+y = 0 $ traversed in the clockwise direction when viewed from $(1,1,0)$.

My attempt:

$∇ \times A = - i -j -k$

S: Surface of intersection of the sphere and the plane. Then definitely S lies on the plane and is bounded by a level curve of the sphere. So, S is given by $x+y = 0$, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Now, a unit normal to S is given by n = $(i + j)/√2$

So, $(∇ \times A)\cdot n = -\sqrt 2$

implies $\int\int ((∇ \times A) \cdot n) \ dS$ reduces to $-\sqrt2 \int\int dS$. Since the plane passes through the origin, the circle it defines in the unit sphere has radius 1. So $\int\int dS = π$.

Hence, the final answer is $-\sqrt{2π}$. I have doubts regarding two things:

(a) Is the above solution correct? I came across this problem in two books. One lists the answer as $-\sqrt{2π}$ while the other says it is $\pi+2$.

(b) How do I ascertain that the unit normal is outward, so that the final answer is positive? Also, I haven't used the statement "traversed in the clockwise direction when viewed from $(1,1,0)$" while solving the question. How do I apply it?

Comment: I think the answer should be $\sqrt{2}\pi$. If you use the fact that $L$ is traversed in the clockwise direction when viewed from $(1,1,0)$, using right hand rule, the unit normal vector should be $-\frac{i+j}{\sqrt{2}}$. And your $S$ should be given by $x+y=0, x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Comment: @KittyL Now I understand the direction of the positive unit normal. Thanks!  But about the surface S. I was thinking it is independent of the z-component. Is my description of the surface wrong? I am having trouble visualizing S.

Comment: Your description does not have a boundary since $x^2+y^2=1$ is a cylinder. The surface $S$ should be a circle that lies in the diagonal plane of $y=-x$ and centered at origin. It should be independent of $z$.

Comment: @KittyL Got it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I meant it shouldn't be independent of z. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The answer is √2π.

(b) Outward normal should be interpreted as per the orientation mentioned in the question.

The unit sphere centred at origin and the plane through origin intersect to form the circle L. S is the surface bounded by this curve L. So S is a disc of unit radius.